# Sending eMail to self using iOS.

Tags: ios, xcode, messageui

I have worked with MFMailComposeViewController via messageUIFramework. I have a case where I have to send email to self. How do i add the "from" address MFMailComposeViewController delegate? any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How to send an email in-APP ?

```
- (IBAction)sendMail:(id)sender {
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

        mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [mailer setSubject:@"Message Pro"];

        //Destination adress
        NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"your adress", nil];
        [mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];

        //Attachement Object
        UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpeg"];
        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);
        [mailer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"mobiletutsImage"]; 

        //Message Body
        NSString *emailBody = @"message body";
        [mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

        [self presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];

        [mailer release];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failure"
                                                        message:@"Your device doesn't support the composer sheet"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}

-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error{
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled: you cancelled the operation and no email message was queued.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved: you saved the email message in the drafts folder.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail send: the email message is queued in the outbox. It is ready to send.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail failed: the email message was not saved or queued, possibly due to an error.");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Mail not sent.");
            break;
    }

    // Remove the mail view
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Don't forgot

1. to add a button with `IBAction` = sendMail
2. to import MessageUI.framework
3. add delegate in your .h file `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`

Answer (score 0):

The "from" address is specified for you by the `MFMailComposeViewController` (and the user can override to be any of their configured mail accounts when they get the compose mail view). You, the programmer, don't have to worry about getting/setting the "from" address.